# Assure correct inputdata with SQL by identifying wrong use of 0 & NULL (COALESCE Logic)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Background information:**

There is a table "ProductCosts". 
The first sample Dataset shows correctly inserted data. 
The data is entered via excel and ingested by an ETL process.
The table shows different Costs. 
The Cost "4_Cost" is the most recent if given, then "3_Costs", and so on.

In this Case "3-Costs" is the most recent given Cost:

```
Category                Product ISOMonth    1_Costs     2_Costs     3_Costs     4_Costs     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     40,000.00   40,000.00   50,000.00   NULL    
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     10,000.00   10,000.00   00.00       NULL    
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     10,000.00   10,000.00   00.00       NULL
```

You see that in row two and three the 10,000.00 from "2_Costs" are replaced with 00.00 by the "3_Costs".
To identify the CurrentCosts the following simple Logic is applied (see COALESCE):

```
SELECT Category
    . Product
    . ISOMonth
    . COALESCE([4_Costs].[3_Costs]. [2_Costs]. [1_Costs]) AS CurrentRRCosts 
FROM [ProductCosts]
```

Correct Result:

```
Category                Product ISOMonth    CurrentCosts
-----------------------------------------------------------
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     50,000.00
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     00.00
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     00.00
```

In the end CurrentCost are summed up, its 50,000.00
That works great if Inputdata is correct.

**Wrong Data:**

```
Category                Product ISOMonth    1_Costs     2_Costs     3_Costs     4_Costs     CurrentCosts
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     40,000.00   40,000.00   50,000.00   NULL        50,000.00
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     10,000.00   10,000.00   NULL        NULL        10,000.00
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     10,000.00   10,000.00   NULL        NULL        10,000.00
```

In this Case the user forgot to enter the 00.00 in row two and row three of column "3_Costs".
That leads to wrong results in the CurrentCosts column:

```
Category                Product ISOMonth    CurrentCosts
--------------------------------------------------------
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     50,000.00
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     10,000.00
ProductCategory1        Stuff   2017-10     10,000.00
```

In the end the CurrentCost are summed up so its 70,000.00
, which is a wrong result just because the user forgot to overwrite the prevoius 10,000.00 with a 00.00

**Assertion:** 
If one Value for a Column like "3_Costs" is NOT NULL (here it is e.g. 50,000.00) 
by category, product and month, the other values should NOT be NULL.

**Wrong data example:**
looking at the data set "wrong data". If there are 50,000.00 given for "3_Costs" in the first row there must also be a value in the seconde and third row.

An SQL query returning a Flag like "has_incomplete_cost_column" would be fine.
Then I would know that the data is not consistent.

determining factors:
I have to keep the existsing data model and Concept coz its already implemented this way.
Input data is provided by an Excel-Sheet so its not about building a User Interface that catches these errors.

Comment: I think you have other issues with your data model.  I don't really get what the problem is or how you can tell which row(s) have the problem.

Comment: So to put it differently, you want the sum of the column furthest to the right when any given row is populated?

Comment: "If there is even one non-null value for column C" -- `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T WHERE C IS NOT NULL)`. "Then none should have property P" -- `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T WHERE NOT (P)) SELECT 'Error'`. The whole can't be applied as a row-level constraint since your logic spans rows. I'm in full agreement with Gordon that this data model is asking for trouble, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about an analytic and case or subqueries to get total per column then use case/ to use the same column every time?

[Demo:](http://rextester.com/UXXM10477)

The fundamental issue is you need the coalesce to occur on the sum of a column, not the individual row; and then only display that rows value not the sum.

```
With ProductCosts(Category,Product, ISOMonth, [1_Costs], [2_Costs], [3_Costs], [4_Costs]) as (
SELECT 'ProductCategory1',        'Stuff',   '2017-10',     40000.00,   40000.00,   50000.00,   cast(NULL as numeric(10,2)) UNION ALL
SELECT 'ProductCategory1',        'Stuff',   '2017-10',     10000.00,   10000.00,   NULL ,     cast(NULL as numeric(10,2)) UNION ALL
SELECT 'ProductCategory1',        'Stuff',   '2017-10',     10000.00,   10000.00,   NULL,       cast(NULL as numeric(10,2)) UNION ALL
SELECT 'ProductCategory1',        'Stuff',   '2017-10',     NULL,        NULL,        NULL,        cast(NULL as numeric(10,2)))


Select Category, Product, ISOMonth, Case when sum([4_costs]) over (partition by Category, Product, ISOMonth) > 0 then [4_costs]
     when sum([3_Costs]) over (partition by Category, Product, ISOMonth)> 0 then [3_Costs]
     when sum([2_costs]) over (partition by Category, Product, ISOMonth)> 0 then [2_costs]
     when sum([1_Costs]) over (partition by Category, Product, ISOMonth)> 0 then [1_costs]
end as currentprice
from productCosts A
```

Giving us (in top or bottom approach)

```
+----+------------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|    |     Category     | Product | ISOMonth | currentprice |
+----+------------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|  1 | ProductCategory1 | Stuff   | 2017-10  | 50000,00     |
|  2 | ProductCategory1 | Stuff   | 2017-10  | NULL         |
|  3 | ProductCategory1 | Stuff   | 2017-10  | NULL         |
|  4 | ProductCategory1 | Stuff   | 2017-10  | NULL         |
+----+------------------+---------+----------+--------------+
```

Few notes:

- Not a big fan of starting a column with a numeric but that's my hangup.
- by using the analytic we are identifying the first column which has a value and using it's value all the time.
- The analytic basically has to run for every record/row this may be slower than calculating it once or calculating it once for each column, put result to a variable and use the variable within a case
- I'm not positive about the partition for each analytic so you may need to adjust.
- This allows the missing 0.00's to be in any row (including the first)
- What's to say someone doesn't put 0.00 in 4_costs and then all totals would be based on that 0.00 in 4_Costs?  You can't control that type of human error. but you could check and report back if the total for a column is 0 indicate to user to check inputs as a "Warning"

Alternative approach; I'm not sure if the analytic repeated or the subqueries would be faster w/o testing. I think the subqueries as I believe they would happen only once whereas the analytic has to run for each row; but maybe the engine knows that and optimized accordingly.

```
Select PC.Category, PC.Product, PC.ISOMonth, Case when D.[4_costs] > 0 then PC.[4_costs]
     when C.[3_Costs]> 0 then PC.[3_Costs]
     when B.[2_Costs]> 0 then PC.[2_costs]
     when A.[1_Costs]> 0 then PC.[1_costs]
end as currentprice
from productCosts PC
INNER join (Select sum([4_costs]) [4_costs], Category, product, ISOMonth from ProductCosts GROUP BY  Category, product, ISOMonth ) D
  on D.Category = PC.Category
 and D.Product = PC.Product
 and D.ISOMonth = PC.ISOMonth
INNER join (Select sum([3_costs]) [3_costs], Category, product, ISOMonth from ProductCosts Group by Category, product, ISOMonth) C
  on C.Category = PC.Category
 and C.Product = PC.Product
 and C.ISOMonth = PC.ISOMonth
INNER join (Select sum([2_costs]) [2_costs], Category, product, ISOMonth from ProductCosts Group by Category, product, ISOMonth ) B
  on B.Category = PC.Category
 and B.Product = PC.Product
 and B.ISOMonth = PC.ISOMonth
INNER join (Select sum([1_costs]) [1_costs], Category, product, ISOMonth from ProductCosts Group by Category, product, ISOMonth ) A
  on A.Category = PC.Category
 and A.Product = PC.Product
 and A.ISOMonth = PC.ISOMonth
```

Comment: Both approaches would definitely work in my case. It is not much data so perfomance is not an issue. Thx